# How to show tooltips onmouseover in p:calendar

Tags: javascript, primefaces, callback, calendar, onmouseover

I want to show tooltips when hovering over certain dates in a `p:calendar` element in PrimeFaces 6.2. I think the way to go is to use global tooltips and change the title of the `a`-elements inside the calendar. How can I access these?

I tried to use the `onmouseover` - attribute of `p:calendar`, hoping to get access to the element as a parameter. As a first step, I wanted to print something to the console:

`calendar.xhtml`:

```
[...]
<h:outputScript library="js" name="calendar.js" />
<p:calendar
      id="calendar"
      value="#{calendarManagedBean.dateToday}"
      mode="inline"
      onmouseover="hoverDate"
      beforeShowDay="colorizeDate"
      />
[...]
```

`calendar.js`:

```
[...]
function hoverDate() {
  console.log("hoverTest");
}
[...]
```

I expect this to print "hoverTest" to the javascript-console of the browser when I hover over dates in the calendar, but it does not do anything. I tried with 0, 1, and 2 parameters for `hoverDate()`. The [documentation](https://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_6_2.pdf) (page 54) only says "Client side callback to execute when a pointer button is moved onto input element.", not saying anything about parameters.

The method `colorizeDate` is in the same javascript-file and works fine, so the problem can't be that the method `hoverDate` cannot be found.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging for future questions

Comment: mouseover is for the full component, not individual dates. I don't think you can have tooltips per date. Inspecting the javascript source will shed a light on this

Comment: Where do I need to look? [This github page](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/tree/6_2) only has the java library.

Comment: look better ;-). (or do a search on *.js in that repo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the comments to your question already hint at, the `mouseover` event of the `p:calendar` component is bound to the parent date input text, not the date picker or the individual dates in the date picker.

Obviously the solution is to manually do this binding in JavaScript. With PrimeFaces 7.0 the following solution should work,

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
        <title>Calendar hover test</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <p:calendar />
        </h:form>       
        <script>
            $(document).on("mouseenter", ".ui-datepicker-calendar td", function() {
                console.log(this.dataset.year, this.dataset.month, this.children[0].textContent);
            });
        </script>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

This will set up a live/dynamic binding on all "td" elements contained under a PrimeFaces date picker table and print out something similar to the following onto the JavaScript console;

```
2019 7 27
2019 7 6
2019 7 13
2019 7 12
2019 7 19
```

Depending on your needs you can also take this further and bind it to a backing bean Java callback using either `h:commandScript` (if you are on JSF 2.3) or `p:remoteCommand`. Then you can also access the Java side when this event happens.

If you are using an older version of PrimeFaces, the class name of the date picker might be different (although I think it has been the same for quite some time). In that case you can use the DOM inspector of the browser to look up the path of the binding.

Comment: Thanks! That was the hint in the right direction that I needed.